# Uploaded a zip file of static website contents to S3 but website shows Error 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404

I successfully deployed a package to S3 via Octopus but I get an **error 404** instead of a website.

According to this [article](https://cloudconfusing.com/2017/12/06/how-to-easily-host-a-static-web-site-on-amazon-web-services-s3-for-almost-free/), the zip file should at least have the `index.html`.

The zip folder that was uploaded already contains the files created by the `npm run build` command.
[image]

Kindly advise. Thanks a lot!